# ORACLE - Pivotar tablas

Tags: sql, oracle

A partir de las siguientes tablas:

```
TABLA1
------
id name
1  n1
2  n2


TABLA2
------
id tipo valor
1  t1   v1
1  t2   v2
2  t1   v1
2  t2   v5
2  t3   v3
```

Estoy intentando obtener lo siguiente:

```
id name t1 t2 t3
1  n1   v1 v2 -
2  n2   v1 v5 v3
```

Estoy mirando ejemplos con la keyword PIVOT pero no  me queda muy claro si se puede hacer esto o cómo. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para el ejemplo expuesto, se puede hacer:

```
Create table tbl1 (id integer, name varchar2(2));
Create table tbl2 (id integer, tipo varchar2(2), valor varchar2(2));

insert into tbl1 (id, name) values(1,'n1');
insert into tbl1 (id, name) values(2,'n2');
```

Ahora el pivot

```
Select * from 
(
    Select tbl1.id, tbl1.name,tbl2.tipo, tbl2.valor
    from tbl1 inner join tbl2 on tbl1.id =tbl2.id
)
as source
pivot(max(valor) for tipo in ([t1],[t2],[t3])) pvt
```

Transponer las filas que contienen los literales t1, t2 y t3 a columnas, y de ellas utilizar la función max.

[image: Resultado]

La documentación de oracle, (aunque en inglés), explica perfectamente como se realiza.

[Pivot](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html)